# Regex - How do I continue looking up for a string if a certain character ":" is found?

Tags: ruby, regex, excel

I wanted to check if the user inputs a correct excel column location. Normally, an excel column can have something like this:

- A
- B
- AA
- BZ
- AAA
- BBB
- AAAA
- .....

But what if I wanted to have a range of column like this:

- A:F
- AB:AD
- CD:CF
- .....

How would I create a Regular Expression that will check if a string matches first the correct column location. If a colon ":" is found, it will continue to check the rest?

So this would be the correct values:

- A
- AB
- A:Z
- BB:CC
- ZA:AAA

Update 1: Here's what I've tried but it failed.
 - /([a-zA-Z]{1,4}:[a-zA-Z]{1,4})/

Update 2: Here is the one I expected but can be improved.
 - /([A-Z]{1,2}:?[A-Z]{1,2})/

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just try setting a range object to the given address - if it fails, it was an invalid address.

Comment: It failed to match what I wanted the app should check. It should check if a single occurence of ":" colon is found, then it will continue searching for another column location.

Comment: Also, columns only go to `XFD` so you would need something like `/[A-X]{1,3}\:[A-Z]{1,3}/`

Comment: @Bajongskie you might need to escape the colon in RegEx with a backslash - `\:`

Comment: I did included it now but still, it fails when there's no occurrence of ":". It should match this: 'AB', 'A:B', 'AA:AB'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close. If you add a start of line and end of line delimiter, then make the second grouping optional, you might get what you need:

```
^([a-zA-Z]{1,4}(?::[a-zA-Z]{1,4})?)$
```

The changes I made were adding `^` to the beginning, `$` to the end, then surrounding the second group with `(?: )?` so that it doesn't pull the second group out as an individual match, and it's also optional.

Here's a Rubular link for reference: http://rubular.com/r/lVLXzMllzF